# ASP.NET: Routing rules

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

coming from PHP background I know that we can configure something like this in CakePHP and CodeIgniter:

To have all request to http://mydomain.com/admin/product/view to be handled by Products controller and admin_view method.

```
public function admin_view()
```

will handle request to /admin/product/view, while

```
public function view()
```

will handle request to /product/view

How do I do this in ASP.NET MVC? Anyone can help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may organize this type of code using the areas concept in asp.net MVC. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) will help.

Comment: suhair, thanks for your response ... I have read about areas concept briefly before ... was under impression that it is for setting up multiple mini-projects/sites? But I will read through the link you provided. Thanks.